# Workbox runtime caching in service worker being ignored

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

In my service worker I have:

```
console.log('register images')

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // Cache image files
  /.*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/,
  // Use the cache if it's available
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    // Use a custom cache name
    cacheName:'image-cache'
  })
);
```

(for example) but no such cache is being created. (but pre-caching is working)

I presume I'm missing something basic. Can't seem to find an example that fixes this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It was the scope of the serviceworker.

I had `sw.js` in `dist/`. Once I moved it to the public root (so scope became `/` all was good.

That answer was REALLY hard to find. Lots if rooting around in the haystack.

For loading offline, I now need to get the serviceworker to respond to navigation request for `/`. I saw a pithy comment that among other things `index.html` needs to be placed in precache manifest (without instructions). Now having fun looking for docs on this for `WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest`. :-(

Comment: For the /index.html fetch i just did
    `self.__precacheManifest.push({revision:'abcd',url:'/index.html'})` (for now)

Comment: thanks for your question and answer @HenrikBechmann! i'm facing same issue when using `InjectManifest` but even in public root this feature of runtime caching from `GenerateSW` is not working. while, it works in the latter mode. Also I would like to point out, as per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list), and maybe you saw this the warning states, "Never hardcode revision info into a "hand written" manifest, as precached URLs will not be kept up to date unless the revision info reflects the URL's contents!"

Comment: I've been using Workbox for a day and I already loathe it. Seems really powerful but the documentation for this tool is so incredibly bad.